# Linux - use of term mount in clone man page

Tags: linux, clone, mount

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22886714/682869) to clarify what mount means in Linux.

I have a doubt in the use of this term in the clone man page:

```
The namespace of a process is the data (the set of mounts) describing the file 
hierarchy as seen by that process.
```

**The set of mounts - describing the file hierarchy** seems misleading to me.

From what I understood based on the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22886776/682869), the file hierarchy could be much more than just the set of mounts, as the set of mounts will be just be the mount points where file systems were added to existing file system.

Can anyone clarify ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think of “the set of mounts” as being (at least) a set of *(device, mount point)* pairs, rather than merely a set of mount *points*, then it starts to look a lot like the `fstab` or the output of the `mount` command (with no arguments), albeit without the additional information about flags and options (e.g. `rw`, `nosuid`, etc.).

Such a “set of mounts” provides complete information about what filesystems are mounted where. This is, by definition, the “mount namespace” of a process. Once you go from the traditional situation of having one global mount namespace to having per-process mount namespaces, additional questions arise when a process `fork()`s.

Traditionally, mounting or unmounting a filesystem changed the filesystem as seen by all processes.

With per-process mount namespaces, it is possible for a child process to have a different mount namespace from its parent. A question now arises:

**Should changes to the mount namespace made by the child propagate back to the parent?**

Clearly, this functionality *must* at least be supported and, indeed, must probably be the default. Otherwise, launching the `mount` command itself would effect no change (since the filesystem as seen by the parent shell would be unaffected).

Equally clearly, it must also be possible for this necessary propagation to be *suppressed*, otherwise we can never create a child process whose mount namespace differs from its parent, and we have one global mount namespace again (the filesystem as seen by `init`).

Thus, we must decide on `fork()` whether the child process gets its own copy of the data about mounted filesystems from the parent, which it can change without affecting the parent, or gets a pointer to the same data structures as the, which it can change (necessary for changes to propagate back, as when you launch `mount` from the shell).

If the `CLONE_NEWNS` flag is passed to `clone()` or `fork()`, the child gets a *copy* of its parent's mounted filesystem data, which it can change without affecting the parent's mount namespace. Otherwise, it gets a *pointer* to the parents data structure, where changes made by the child will be seen by the parent (so the `mount` command itself can work).

Comment: So the file system has no directories other than the mount points ?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by “filesystem”. People use it pretty loosely to mean the complete structure of all the files and directories, on the one hand, but also for the format in which these are organized in a partition (as in “ext4 filesystem”) and a lot of things in between.

Comment: I am referring to file system as a hierarchy of directories (the complete structure of all files and directories).

Comment: In that case, a list of devices and their mount-points clearly isn't sufficient. I guess I was thinking at a somewhat different level where, for a certain loose meaning of “filesystem”, it is adequately described merely by the output of `mount`, for example.

Comment: Considering file system as complete set of files and directories, and mount points as directories where other file systems are mounted, could you please edit your answer and share your opinion on use of the term 'mount' in the given sentence in the clone man page (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html), thanks.

Comment: I am going to ask a related question to clarify the meaning of CLONE_NEWNS. If you could answer that as well, it would be really helpful, thanks !! (I'll post the link).

Comment: I've updated my answer. I'll modify it for your new question.